# Stumped by what appears to be a simple algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I was taking a test online and ran into the following. The questions have a strict time limit (20 seconds or so) so it caught me offguard

> A restaurant sold 250 drinks in a night. Some of the drinks were sold
> for \$2 each, and the rest for \$5 each. If the total sales of drinks
> for the night was \$830, how many $2 drinks were sold?

Possible answers: 110, 140, 145, 150, 155.

It looks like a substitution problem but it ground my gears to a halt. What am I missing here? You're supposed to be able to figure this out in just a few seconds. I'd like to know how to approach these.

Comment: Let $x$ be the number of $\$2$ drinks, and $y$ be the number of $\$5$ drinks. Solve for $x$ by using the information given in the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algebra is fixed, but in time pressure, it may come down to intuition.

If all 250 drinks sold for $\$2$ you would be $\$(830 - 500) = \$330$ short.

Changing 1 drink from $\$2$ to $\$5$ increases sales by $\$3$.  So you need to convert $110$ drinks, leaving $(250 - 110) = 140$ drinks remaining as $\$2$ drinks.

Mirror image - alternate approach.

If all drinks sold for $5$, you would be $\$(1250 - 830) = \$420$ over.  Each drink converted from $\$5$ to $\$2$ drops sales by $\$3$.  So you need to convert $\frac{420}{3} = 140$ drinks to $\$2$ drinks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $x + y = 250$ and $2x + 5y = 830.$  Then $2x + 2y = 500$. Subtract the last two equations to get $3y = 330$.  So $y = 110$ and $x = 250  - 110 = 140.$

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot (and rings a very distant bell)